# Oracle error ORA-06532 when I try to populate a table that has a vararray attribute

Tags: arrays, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I am trying to populate a table that has an Vararray with data that in a table called **fv_16dim**.

For doing so I am using the following code:

Create the vararray type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE fv_integer_varray AS VARRAY(16) OF INTEGER NOT NULL;
```

create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE cophirfv_vararray (
id NUMBER,
fv fv_integer_varray,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Create a function that returns a vararray according to the table's ID.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_VC_Array_MInteger(p_id NUMBER) 
RETURN fv_integer_varray
IS
     varray_integer fv_integer_varray := fv_integer_varray();
BEGIN
    varray_integer.EXTEND(16);

    SELECT fv.dim1 ,
                        fv.dim2 ,
                        fv.dim3 ,
                        fv.dim4 ,
                        fv.dim5 ,
                        fv.dim6 ,
                        fv.dim7 ,
                        fv.dim8 ,
                        fv.dim9,
                        fv.dim10 ,
                        fv.dim11 ,
                        fv.dim12 ,
                        fv.dim13,
                        fv.dim14,
                        fv.dim15,
                        fv.dim16 
INTO  varray_integer(0), varray_integer(1), varray_integer(2), varray_integer(3),
      varray_integer(4), varray_integer(5), varray_integer(6), varray_integer(7),
      varray_integer(8), varray_integer(9), varray_integer(10),
      varray_integer(11), varray_integer(12), varray_integer(13), 
      varray_integer(14), varray_integer(15)
FROM fv_16dim fv WHERE id = p_id;

RETURN varray_integer;

END;
/
```

The procedure that populates the table **cophirfv_vararray**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE populate_cophirfv_vararray
AS
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..200000 LOOP
        INSERT INTO cophirfv_vararray (id,fv) 
        SELECT i, insert_VC_Array_MInteger(i) FROM dual;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Then I execute the command:

```
EXEC populate_cophirfv_vararray;
```

But I am getting the error:

```
SQL> EXEC populate_cophirfv_vararray;
BEGIN populate_cophirfv_vararray; END;

*
ERRO na linha 1:
ORA-06532: Subscript outside of limit
ORA-06512: em "HIGIIA.INSERT_VC_ARRAY_MINTEGER", line 7
ORA-06512: em "HIGIIA.POPULATE_COPHIRFV_VARARRAY", line 5
ORA-06512: em line 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
INTO varray_integer(1), varray_integer(2), varray_integer(3), varray_integer(4),
   varray_integer(5), varray_integer(6), varray_integer(7), varray_integer(8),
   varray_integer(9), varray_integer(10), varray_integer(11), varray_integer(12),
   varray_integer(13), varray_integer(14), varray_integer(15), array_integer(16)
--...
```

---

Range: 0-15 should be 1-16. From [PL/SQL Collections and Records](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/05_colls.html)

> To reference an element, you use standard subscripting syntax (see Figure 5-2). For example, Grade(3) references the third element in varray Grades.
>
> Figure 5-2 Varray of Size 10
>   [image]